# How to change color when fade out and revert back on fade in upon new data retrieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you change the color of a text for X amount of second and revert back to normal when there is new data updated on the page.

```
function displayPrice() {
fetch_price();
const price = json[0];
document.getElementById('current_price').innerHTML = `$${price}`;
$('current_price').fadeOut(500);
//if price is greater than previous price, set current_price color to green
//else set current_price color to red
$('current_price').fadeIn(500);
//set current_price color to white
});
}

setInterval(displayPrice, 5000);
```

**Code update:**

```
const API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=NZD';
function displayPrice() {
fetch(API_URL)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
const price = json[0];
document.getElementById('btc_usd').innerHTML = `$${topCoin.price_usd}`;
$('btc_usd').fadeOut(500);
$('btc_usd').fadeIn(500);
 });
}
setInterval(displayPrice, 5000);
```

Comment: Your code has typos, and doesn't make much sense. What does `fetch_price` do? Where's the JSON coming from?

Comment: fetch_price is a function that I use to retrieve price in json format from another website via their API URL. This price will be update to the innerHTML of current_price id. everything works but I just dont know how to make the current_price id fade out and in.

Comment: `fetch_price` should be an async function. As it stands your code will not work because the JSON is apparently appearing out of nowhere. You should probably fix that first.

Comment: I have fixed the typo and update the code. I still cant see if jquery fade out and in is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Use callback after fadeOut like this: (I don't know your "current_price" is id or class, also use a var to save previous price like p_price)

```
$(this).find("#current_price").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    if (price > p_price) {
        $(this).css({color:"green"});
    } else {
        $(this).css({color:"red"});
    }
});
```

And also for fadeIn.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to got it to work. I was missing the # all along..

```
$("#current_price").css({color:"#4CAF50"});
$('#current_price').fadeOut(500);
$('#current_price').fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeToggle() method for implementing your scenario. Call this method after few seconds and to make normal if value is there.

Input value

```
<input type="text" id="current_price" onchange="return ChangeValue(this);"/>



 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#current_price').on('change', ChangeValue)
    {
     $('current_price').fadeToggle();
    } 
    });
```